# After adding suggested semicolons throughout my js code, I'm now getting a parsing error, unexpected token at the end of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an unexpected token or Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.
I wasn't getting this before. It seems as though I didn't get the error until I added semicolons throughout the code to end the statements. I can't figure out what broke.

```js
//This is the state
var pokemonDB = [{
  name: 'charmander',
  type: 'fire',
  hp: 39,
  attack: 52,
  defense: 43,
  level: 1,
  img: 'http://www.smogon.com/dex/media/sprites/xy/charmander.gif'
}, {
  name: 'bulbasaur',
  type: 'water',
  hp: 45,
  attack: 49,
  defense: 49,
  level: 1,
  img: 'http://www.smogon.com/dex/media/sprites/xy/bulbasaur.gif'
}, {
  name: 'squirtle',
  type: 'water',
  hp: 44,
  attack: 48,
  defense: 65,
  level: 1,
  img: 'http://www.smogon.com/dex/media/sprites/xy/squirtle.gif'
}, ]

var gameState = {
  userPokemon: "",
  rivalPokemon: ""
}
console.log[gameState]
//This is the elements
var pokemonsEl = document.querySelector('.select-screen').querySelectorAll('.character')
console.log(pokemonsEl)
var battleScreenEl = document.getElementById('battle-screen')
var attackBtnsEl = document.getElementById('battle-screen').querySelectorAll('.attack')
console.log(attackBtnsEl)

var i = 0
//This is the initial loop
while (i < pokemonsEl.length) {
  //Add function to all characters on screen selected
  pokemonsEl[i].onclick = function() {
    //current selected pokemons name
    var pokemonName = this.dataset.pokemon
    //elements for images on battlescreen
    var player1Img = document.querySelector('.player1').getElementsByTagName('img')
    var player2Img = document.querySelector('.player2').getElementsByTagName('img')
    //save current pokemon
    gameState.userPokemon = pokemonName;

    cpuPick()
    battleScreenEl.classList.toggle('active')

    gameState.currentPokemon = pokemonDB.filter(function(pokemon) {
      return pokemon.name == gameState.userPokemon;
    })

    player1Img[0].src = gameState.currentPokemon[0].img
    //select data from current cpu
    gameState.currentRivalPokemon = pokemonDB.filter(function(pokemon) {
      return pokemon.name == gameState.rivalPokemon;
    })
    player2Img[0].src = gameState.currentRivalPokemon[0].img

    //current user and cpu initial health
    gameState.currentPokemon[0].health = calculateInitialHealth(gameState.currentPokemon)
    gameState.currentRivalPokemon[0].health = calculateInitialHealth(gameState.currentRivalPokemon)
    console.log(gameState)
  }
  i++
}

var a = 0;
while (a < attackBtnsEl.length) {
  attackBtnsEl[a].onclick = function() {
    var attackName = this.dataset.attack
    gameState.currentUserAttack = attackName

    play(attackName, cpuAttack())
  }
  a++
}

var cpuAttack = function() {
    var attacks = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    return attacks[randomNumber(0, 3)]

    var calculateInitialHealth = function(user) {
      return ((0.20 * Math.sqrt(user[0].level)) * user[0].defense) * user[0].hp
    }

    var attackMove = function(attack, level, stack, critical, enemy, attacker) {
      console.log(enemy.name + ' before: ' + enemy.health)
      var attackAmount = ((attack * level) * (stack * critical))
      enemy.health = enemy.health - attackAmount
      checkWinner(enemy, attacker)
      console.log(enemy.name + ' after: ' + enemy.health)
    }

    var checkWinner = function(enemy, attacker) {
      if (enemy.health <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = ('You Win ' + attacker.name + '!');
        console.log('You Win ' + attacker.name + '!')
      }
    }

    var play = function(userAttack, cpuAttack) {
      var currentPokemon = gameState.currentPokemon[0]
      var currentRivalPokemon = gameState.currentRivalPokemon[0]

      switch (userAttack) {
        case 'rock':
          if (cpuAttack == 'paper')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER</strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }

          if (cpuAttack == 'scissors')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses SCISSORS</strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }

          if (cpuAttack == 'rock')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses ROCK</strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .1, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
          break;
        case 'paper':
          if (cpuAttack == 'paper')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER </strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)

              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
          if (cpuAttack == 'scissors')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses SCISSORS</strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {

                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
          if (cpuAttack == 'rock')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses ROCK </strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {

                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
          break;
        case 'scissors':
          if (cpuAttack == 'paper')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER </strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {

                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
          if (cpuAttack == 'scissors')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses SCISSORS </strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {

                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
          if (cpuAttack == 'rock')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses ROCK </strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {

                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    var randomNumber = function(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
    }
    var cpuPick = function() {
      gameState.rivalPokemon = pokemonsEl[randomNumber(0, 3)].dataset.pokemon
    }
```

Comment: The code is still in a state that semicolon fans would consider incorrect.

Comment: Using consistent indentation as in the edited update to your question, you can generally spot missing `}` characters and other things like that. In this case, it looks like `cpuAttack()` is missing a closing `}`.

Comment: have you used a developer tools in a browser to detect the location of the first occurrence of your error? Tools will tell you exactly where the first instance of the error is so you can fix it. Repeat until all errors are fixed.

Comment: Also; would you mind posting the code that includes the semicolons... or did you think that was the code with semicolons? because your code is syntactically prone to error the way it is posted at this time.

Comment: @William Watts: did you solve the problem?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru yes, it works. I appreciate all of the help from you guys. But,  I can't seem to point out where the changes are that made the code work.

Comment: @daddygames yes, I do. In fact, I don't think you can complete any project without it lol. But, unfortunately, it only gives me the error at the end of the code, not the beginning from the first occurrence.

Comment: @WilliamWatts: see curvy brackets

Comment: I went on the move most of the variables and loops in the gameState object to clean up the code and initialized a new function for the while loops. New code works fine and I made sure to close everything with semicolons. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

In the pokemonDB array, you have a comma after the last object which it shouldn't be there

Answer (score -1):

I set semicolons in ends of lines and set curvy brackets where is needed, like this one:

```
case 'rock':
          if (cpuAttack == 'paper')
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER</strong>"; {
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
              attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
              if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
              }
            }
          }
```

I moved the curly bracket from the end of the line to the "if"-end of the line

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER</strong>"; {
```

And I've got:

```
case 'rock':
              if (cpuAttack == 'paper') {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER</strong>";
                if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                  attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon)
                  if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon)
                  }
                }
              }
```

Full code:

```
//This is the state
var pokemonDB = [{
    name: 'charmander',
    type: 'fire',
    hp: 39,
    attack: 52,
    defense: 43,
    level: 1,
    img: 'http://www.smogon.com/dex/media/sprites/xy/charmander.gif'
}, {
    name: 'bulbasaur',
    type: 'water',
    hp: 45,
    attack: 49,
    defense: 49,
    level: 1,
    img: 'http://www.smogon.com/dex/media/sprites/xy/bulbasaur.gif'
}, {
    name: 'squirtle',
    type: 'water',
    hp: 44,
    attack: 48,
    defense: 65,
    level: 1,
    img: 'http://www.smogon.com/dex/media/sprites/xy/squirtle.gif'
}];

var gameState = {
    userPokemon: "",
    rivalPokemon: ""
};

console.log[gameState];
//This is the elements
var pokemonsEl = document.querySelector('.select-screen').querySelectorAll('.character');
console.log(pokemonsEl);
var battleScreenEl = document.getElementById('battle-screen');
var attackBtnsEl = document.getElementById('battle-screen').querySelectorAll('.attack');
console.log(attackBtnsEl);

var i = 0;
//This is the initial loop
while (i < pokemonsEl.length) {
    //Add function to all characters on screen selected
    pokemonsEl[i].onclick = function() {
        //current selected pokemons name
        var pokemonName = this.dataset.pokemon;
        //elements for images on battlescreen
        var player1Img = document.querySelector('.player1').getElementsByTagName('img');
        var player2Img = document.querySelector('.player2').getElementsByTagName('img');
        //save current pokemon
        gameState.userPokemon = pokemonName;

        cpuPick();
        battleScreenEl.classList.toggle('active');

        gameState.currentPokemon = pokemonDB.filter(function(pokemon) {
            return pokemon.name == gameState.userPokemon;
        })

        player1Img[0].src = gameState.currentPokemon[0].img;
        //select data from current cpu
        gameState.currentRivalPokemon = pokemonDB.filter(function(pokemon) {
            return pokemon.name == gameState.rivalPokemon;
        })
        player2Img[0].src = gameState.currentRivalPokemon[0].img;

        //current user and cpu initial health
        gameState.currentPokemon[0].health = calculateInitialHealth(gameState.currentPokemon);
        gameState.currentRivalPokemon[0].health = calculateInitialHealth(gameState.currentRivalPokemon);
        console.log(gameState);
    };
    i++;
}

var a = 0;
while (a < attackBtnsEl.length) {
    attackBtnsEl[a].onclick = function() {
        var attackName = this.dataset.attack;
        gameState.currentUserAttack = attackName;

        play(attackName, cpuAttack());
    };
    a++;
}

var cpuAttack = function() {
    var attacks = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    return attacks[randomNumber(0, 3)];
};

var calculateInitialHealth = function(user) {
    return ((0.20 * Math.sqrt(user[0].level)) * user[0].defense) * user[0].hp;
};

var attackMove = function(attack, level, stack, critical, enemy, attacker) {
    console.log(enemy.name + ' before: ' + enemy.health);
    var attackAmount = ((attack * level) * (stack * critical));
    enemy.health = enemy.health - attackAmount;
    checkWinner(enemy, attacker);
    console.log(enemy.name + ' after: ' + enemy.health);
};

var checkWinner = function(enemy, attacker) {
    if (enemy.health <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = ('You Win ' + attacker.name + '!');
        console.log('You Win ' + attacker.name + '!');
    }
};

var play = function(userAttack, cpuAttack) {
    var currentPokemon = gameState.currentPokemon[0];
    var currentRivalPokemon = gameState.currentRivalPokemon[0];

    switch (userAttack) {
        case 'rock':
        if (cpuAttack == 'paper') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER</strong>"; 
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }


        if (cpuAttack == 'scissors') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses SCISSORS</strong>"; 
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }

        if (cpuAttack == 'rock') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses ROCK</strong>";
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .1, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case 'paper':
        if (cpuAttack == 'paper'){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER </strong>"; 
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);

                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }

        if (cpuAttack == 'scissors') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses SCISSORS</strong>";
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }

        if (cpuAttack == 'rock') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses ROCK </strong>";
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case 'scissors':
        if (cpuAttack == 'paper') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses PAPER </strong>";
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }

        if (cpuAttack == 'scissors') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses SCISSORS </strong>";
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 1, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }

        if (cpuAttack == 'rock') {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<strong>cpu chooses ROCK </strong>";
            if (currentPokemon.health >= 1 && currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                attackMove(currentPokemon.attack, currentPokemon.level, .8, .5, currentRivalPokemon, currentPokemon);
                if (currentRivalPokemon.health >= 1) {
                    attackMove(currentRivalPokemon.attack, currentRivalPokemon.level, .8, 2, currentPokemon, currentRivalPokemon);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
};

var randomNumber = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

var cpuPick = function() {
    gameState.rivalPokemon = pokemonsEl[randomNumber(0, 3)].dataset.pokemon;
};
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but your answer does not help explain what was changed to fix the issue. I assume this is why someone else downvoted.

Comment: Of course, downvote is simpler than editing the answer